# How I can get the image from URL in Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks

I have some URL string, how I can get the image from URL? I'm using VisualWorks 9.2

Comment: I'm not a VW user so I cannot answer. However, I would start my search by looking for ways to transform the string into a URL object (presumably `#asURL`) and then going thru senders of it until some insight tells me what to find next. My guess is that something on the lines of `aString asURL asFilename binaryContents` would probably work or fail at a point where I can start debugging and gaining some initial understanding.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia Thank you for your answer! :) I will try answer from the answer section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(URI fromString: yourString) readStream` will produce a stream to read the data from.

You can also use `HttpClient get: url`.

You may want to load the `TLS plugin` parcel in oder to support https.